# RxJS create new Observable "Array" from and static array in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am able to create observable from an array but its `type` is `Observable<number>` not `Observable<number[]>`

```
getUsers(ids: string[]): Observable<number[]> {
   const arraySource = Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
   //output: 1,2,3,4,5
   const subscribe = arraySource.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

   let returnObserable = Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
   return returnObserable; //error at this line, because of the return type
}
```

Is there any other way to create observable other than from ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the entire array to be emitted as a single emissions use `Observable.of` instead:

```
const arraySource = Observable.of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

`Observable.from` iterates the array and emits each item separately while `Observable.of` takes it as without any further logic.

Alternatively, you could also nest two arrays but that's probably too confusing:

```
const arraySource = Observable.from([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]);
```

Comment: `Observable.of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` this worked, then what is the use of `Observable.of([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I wanted to write `Observable.from([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])`

Comment: @martin .. sorry for late comment..had one doubt...when using `.of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` and binding to HTML using `async` pipe works well. However using `.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` and binding with async pipe gives an error .. I am wondering why so ?